# php preg_match utf-8 strange behaviour

Tags: php, regex, utf-8, preg-match

I search the internet but I couldn't find a proper answer so I try this way.

I use this code to validate UTF-8 input. I want to allow printable chars and some specified special chars.

```
$pattern = '/[^\w\.\-\s\,\&\!\?\(\)\+\_\:\;]+$/u';
$status = @preg_match($pattern, $value);
if (($status === false) || ($status > 0)) {
    return false;
}
```

Everything works fine, EXCEPT the input string has at the end a non ascii char (eg. é). Then my validation fails, but it should not.
I know it might be a silly mistake, but thanks in advance for every proposal.

best regards

Comment: You don’t need to escape every character. This suffices: `'/[^\w.\-\s,&!?()+_:;]+$/u'`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try [Unicode character properties](http://php.net/regexp.reference.unicode.php):

```
/[^\p{L}.\-\s,&!?()+_:;]+$/u
```

Here `\p{L}` represents any Unicode character that is categorized as a letter.

Comment: the following script works now: '/[^\p{L}\p{Nd}.\-\s,&!?()+_:;]+$/u' adding the \p{Nd} for the digits, thanks for your answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

use `\pL` to match any letter character